# Overflow in SML: Exponentiation procedure

Tags: overflow, sml, exponentiation

I'm trying to write a simple procedure that calculates x to the power of 17 in the language Standard ML. I'm supposed to do it with a "helping procedure":

```
fun help (y:int) = y * y * y * y;

fun power17 (x:int) = help (help (help (help (x) ) ) ) * x;
```

This causes an overflow. Can somebody tell me why it does so?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an Integer Overflow. If you want your code to work, you need to use `LargeInt.int`.

```
  fun help (y: LargeInt.int) = y * y * y * y;

  fun power17 (x: int) =
    let
      val x' = Int.toLarge x
    in
      help (help (help (help (x')))) * x'
    end;
```

One more thing, that code is not calculating `x ** 17`, instead it's doing `x ** 257`.

You should only call `help` twice:

```
  fun power17 (x:int) = (help (help x)) * x;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function does not calculate the power of 17. Evaluating it:

```
power17 2 ~> help (help (help (help x))) * 2
          ~> help (help (help (2 * 2 * 2 * 2))) * 2 (* that's 2^5 *)
          ~> help (help (help (8))) * 2
          ~> help (help (8 * 8 * 8 * 8)) * 2        (* that's 2^13 *)
          ~> help (help (4096)) * 2
          ~> help (4096 * 4096 * 4096 * 4096) * 2   (* that's 2^49 *)
          ~> raise Overflow (* most SML compilers have 32-bit ints *)
```

Perhaps you meant to write:

```
fun power17 x = help x * help x * help x * help x * x
```

It sounds like an ideal case for recursion, though:

```
fun power (x, 0) = 1
  | power (x, n) = x * power (x, n-1)

fun power17 x = power (x, 17)
```